# Is there an appropriate way to advertise a puzzle question from MathSE here?

Tags: discussion, questions, etiquette, policy

Suppose there's a question over on [MathSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/) under the tag  [[puzzle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/puzzle)]  that, among all questions tagged puzzle, I think would especially be of interest to the users here on PuzzlingSE. Also, it's a question I really want answered :P. Is there an appropriate way to bring this question to the attention of PuzzlingSE users?

- One idea would be to cross-post the question, but I think there's a general agreement that duplicates should be avoided across SE sites for the sake of good housekeeping (can't mark-as-duplicate across sites).
- I could bring it up in chat, in [The Sphinx's Lair](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14524/the-sphinxs-lair) I presume (great name btw), but then I don't think that would reach a very wide audience.

Does anyone have any appropriate suggestions?

Comment: I think that bringing it to chat may expose it to more than you may think

Comment: Linking to it here might help as well...

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain I was going to throw a bounty on it, and post it places when I've got a wee bit more time to be attentive to the post.

Answer (score 1):

IF it's not getting appropriate attention on the stack where it was originally posted

> this generally means:
>
> - it has no positively scored answers
> - it has no accepted answer
> - the view count demonstrates it's not being seen much

AND it would be a good fit somewhere else

> this generally means:
>
> - it's on-topic for a different stack
> - it fits the local customs and requirements for the different stack
> - it doesn't violate rule 1 of migrations: "don't migrate crap"

THEN *the original poster* can request a migration of a question to the other stack.
These requests are usually honored.
Migrations can *sometimes* happen even without the OP requesting it, but that's a harder sell; we don't really want to be seen as poaching questions from elsewhere.

---

So if it makes sense to migrate, rather than merely point to it, it's always an option to just get the question migrated from Math.SE to Puzzling.

Short of that, a mention in our chat room is probably the best bet. It may not seem very active, but a lot of our site's most active puzzlers pop in and out of there and at least read what's going on, even if not contributing to the conversation.